# Draco compression/decompression with .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, rhino3d

I have a requirement to decompress **draco** compressed point clouds being received in a .NET 6 service. I have explored Rhino3dm (version 8.0.1) package for this purpose but could not find the relevant methods.

Has anyone implemented a similar use case and has an idea on how to use Rhino or a different package for this purpose?

Comment: Do you know that this functionality exist in Rhino3dm? If you are looking for library recommendations -> https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you for the link, I will have a look there. 
Yes Rhino inherently uses draco compression - https://developer.rhino3d.com/api/rhinocommon/rhino.fileio.dracocompression?version=8.x